# May I use numeric in a javascript object?

Tags: javascript

It is my understanding that objects' keys are always strings. However, I believe numeric values would be translated to string if used as key, implying it would not be some kind of forbidden value type.
Since we don't use quotes around string keys, writing stuff like this :

```
{
    a: "a_value",
    b: "b_value", [...]
}
```

... I thought it could be easier to read stuff like that :

```
{
    1: "first_value",
    4: "whatever", [...]
}
```

So my question is : is it really considered bad practise to use numeric values as keys, or may I do it, at least for the sake or readability ?

Thanks.

Comment: So you're asking specifically about the identifier syntax in object literals?

Comment: An Object with numeric indexes? That's called an Array.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking. If you know that all property values are converted to string, then why would it matter if the string is numeric?

Comment: @am not i am : Well, I know JavaScript can do it, but that would not necessarily mean it's ok to do so. That could be some kind of bad practice or whatever.

Comment: @Derek : you're right, I could have gone with arrays, but still I find what I wrote as an example way more readable than : 
myArray[1] = "abc";
myArray[4] = "def";

Comment: -- EDIT -- nevermind : creating an array with only two values whose keys would be 1 and 4 would create an array of length 4. I'm mapping keyboard code values so I'd rather not waste so much for no reason.

Comment: @nseptier: JavaScript arrays are sparse. They're really just Objects, and the `.length` just represents the highest index + 1. There's no allocation for the holes in the Array. `myArray[1] = "abc"; myArray[4] = "def"; 3 in myArray; // false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that property names must be strings, but the conversion is done for you. That is, `o = {1: "test""}` is the same thing as `o = {"1": "test"}`. Similarly, `o[45]` and `o[45] = "hi"` both convert the property name for you, using `toString()`.

Here's a quick demonstration, where I've overridden `toString()` to make it obvious:

```
var o = {xyz: 100, toString: function() { console.log("someone string'd me"); return "ooo"; }}
var x = {};

x[o] = "test";
// console says "someone stringed me"

console.log(x["ooo"]);
// console says "test";

console.log(x[o]);
// console says "someone string'd me", then "test"
```

You can see each time `o` is used as a property it's implicitly converted to a string using `o.toString()`. So to be clear, using numeric keys is not a problem. In fact, you can test`["hi", "ol", "dad"]["1"]` and see it is the same thing as ["hi", "ol", "dad"][1]`.

Answer (score 2):

*Any* value can be used as a property in a JavaScript object with one catch - as noted `[ToString]` is invoked upon the value to get the property name<sup>1</sup>.

Hence, the object literal `{1: "hi"}` is equivalent to `{"1": "hi"}`.

Now, the [*Object Initialiser*](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.5) syntax allowed is `{PropertyName: AssignmentExpression, ..}` where PropertyName can *only* be an IdentifierName (`x`), StringLiteral (`"1"`), or NumericLiteral (`1`). Other values can still be used as keys - just not declared using the object initialiser syntax.

Example of an invalid literal, and how to rewrite it using normal property assignment:

```
x = {/regex/: "y"};        // invalid - only Name/String/Number allowed
x = {}; x[/regex/] = "y";  // "okay" - but very suspect!
```

That being said, I can't say I've ever used an "integer property" *except* when dealing with Arrays .. this doesn't make it wrong, even if potentially suspect.

---

<sup>1</sup>This applies to property access (e.g. `obj[x] = y`) but not directly to object initialisers because IdentifierNames are *not* treated as expressions - the end result of all property names being strings still applies, however.